# Requiring unknown module react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Error screen

Using:

```
"react": "15.3.1",
"react-native": "0.32.0",
```

[image: errorimage.png]

Comment: Is react-native installed? Try `npm install` one more time.

Comment: Trying to restart the packager could help too

Comment: I have tried everything `npm install` and `react-native start`. nothing worked.

Answer (score 4):

Reopening the project worked for me for a similar issue.

Requiring unknown module "687".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are missing the node_modules folder from your react native project directory.

First steps are to check:

- Is the node_modules folder in the same directory as your react-native
  project (and where you are running the react-native start command
  from) if so, ensure it has the react-native module inside.
- Check that package.json in your project directory has the following
  under 'dependencies' and then re-run npm install: "react": "15.3.1",
  "react-native": "0.32.0",
- If the correct files are inside the project directory then exit
  the terminal/any programs related to running the code (xCode etc.)
  and perform a 'react-native init ProjectName' and then 'npm install'
  again.

The missing file is a part of the react-native core code so missing it implies something has gone wrong with the react-native installation or runtime paths.